# Center ImageView in ScrollView with paging enabled - Swift

Tags: swift, imageview, scrollview, paging

I need to create a paging ScrollView which shows a sequence of images.

I created a ScrollView in the main view of the Storyboard and set this constraints (to center the ScrollView in the view):

[Constraint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0KKO.png)

Then I activated paging and disabled the "Content layout guides" option.

Next, in the view class I set up the UIScrollViewDelegate delegate and I wrote the following code to show 3 images (they are 3 colored squares):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

// Outlet
@IBOutlet weak var scrollview: UIScrollView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    scrollview.delegate = self;

    let infoArray = ["01", "02", "03"];

    for i in 0..<infoArray.count {
        let imageView = UIImageView();
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleToFill;
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: infoArray[i]);
        let xPos = CGFloat(i) * scrollview.bounds.size.width;
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: xPos, y: 0, width: scrollview.bounds.size.width, height: scrollview.bounds.size.height);
        imageView.layer.borderWidth = 1;

        scrollview.contentSize.width = scrollview.frame.size.width * CGFloat(i+1);
        scrollview.contentSize.height = scrollview.frame.size.height;

        scrollview.addSubview(imageView);
    }

    scrollview.layer.borderWidth = 1;
}
```

}

I have set that the images must have the same width and height as the scrollview. But these are larger in the simulator (and in my iPhone 11) and therefore the display is incorrect. I show you the sequence of the 3 squares:

[Page 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOhDK.png)

[Page 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdJku.png)

[Page 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eviW6.png)

[Page 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUZli.png)

I can't understand where I'm wrong. Why don't the 3 images take the size of the scrollview?
Why are there 4 pages?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you share your paging logic?

Comment: Hi. Do you mean an example of the final result? I have not yet prepared the final images to be inserted in the app interface.

Comment: I meant, can you share your scrolling implementation? How did you implement paging?

Comment: In the Main.Storyboard, i have select the ScrollView and i have flagged "Paging enabled" in attributes inspector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, here is how you do it:

1. Your scrollview is created in storyboard and its layout is set. Make sure content layout guides is unchecked in the size inspector and paging is checked in the attribute inspector.
2. Add a stackview as a subview to your scrollview (this will act as the content view). Pin your stackView to all 4 edges of the scrollView.
3. Set Height and Width Equal to the scrollView height and width. Set the Width priority to 250. (that indicates that the scrollview will scroll horizontally)
4. Set the stackView to horizontal axis, fill alignment and fillEqually distribution.
5. Now, go back to viewDidLoad and add the following code below. ScrollViewContentView is the stackView that acts as a contentView for the scrollView. Note that since stackView is set to fillEqually, you only need set one of the image's width constraint.

   ```
   scrollViewContentView.addArrangedSubview(image1)
   scrollViewContentView.addArrangedSubview(image2)
   scrollViewContentView.addArrangedSubview(image3)

   image1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
   image2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
   image3.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

   image1.backgroundColor = .blue
   image2.backgroundColor = .yellow
   image3.backgroundColor = .red

   image1.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
   ```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the reply. "Almost everything" works.

I did not understand how to do point number 3. The height and width of the scrollview is dynamic, because it is linked by Contraints.
How do I set the same height and width?

By following all the steps except the number 3, it works. But the height of the stackview is too large and the scrollview also scrolls vertically.

Comment: You have to select the scrollView and the stackView at the same time, then click the constraints icon at the bottom right of the middle panel, and check off equal heights and equal widths.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to state the frame of the scrollview before you declare the imageViews x positions or widths.

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

// Outlet
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollview: UIScrollView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        scrollview.frame = view.frame // declared here
        scrollview.delegate = self;

        let infoArray = ["01", "02", "03"];

        for i in 0..<infoArray.count {
            let imageView = UIImageView();
            imageView.contentMode = .scaleToFill;
            imageView.image = UIImage(named: infoArray[i]);
            let xPos = CGFloat(i) * scrollview.bounds.size.width;
            imageView.frame = CGRect(x: xPos, y: 0, width: scrollview.bounds.size.width, height: scrollview.bounds.size.height);
            imageView.layer.borderWidth = 1;

            scrollview.contentSize.width = scrollview.frame.size.width * CGFloat(i+1);
            scrollview.contentSize.height = scrollview.frame.size.height;

            scrollview.addSubview(imageView);
        }

        scrollview.layer.borderWidth = 1;
    }
}
```